# How to Perform Full Truncate and Reload for Daily files in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to delete all files in ADLS target folder and reload them Daily.
How to perform it here in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Did you look at the "Delete" activity?

Comment: Delete active can help you delete all the files in ADLS, but what do you mean reload them daily?